# Unable to join a windows PC to a Samba active directory domain

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

Summary; I am attempting to build an Ubuntu 22.04.03 samba domain controller as part of a very small domain.  This is not for file-sharing.

Problem:  I cannot get a Windows 10 PC to join the domain.  The error message is: `The following error occured attempting to join the domain 'mennenoh'. The user name or password is incorrect.`

Details:  I ensured I was using the correct password with the account.
The account is the account I built the domain controller with and has sudo administrator rights.
The account has been added to samba.
In testing samba and smb appear to be running properly.

Questions:  How do I correct this unexpected outcome?  Do I need to create a different user?  Is this even a permissions issue?

Thanks in advance.  Phil